# Nesting different hashing algorithms?

Tags: hash, cryptography

I'm not at all even intermediate user of cryptographic tools for programming, but through many posts about hashing here I got interested in it.

So, my question is: would nesting of two or more different hashing algorithms be more efficient in securing the data than, for instance, iterating of the same hashing algorithm, in terms of raising the time or inconvenience of attacking such kind of system?

Or, if you like, would

PBKDF2(SHA512(PBKDF2(data+salt1+etc).salt2).salt3)...

be better than

PBKDF2(PBKDF2(PBKDF2(data+salt1+etc).salt2).salt3)?

(Three nested algorithms written for simplicity, in real app supposedly there would be thousands of them)

Thank you,

Edi

Comment: The point of `PBKDF2` is to require computation time. Also `PBKDF2` has a cost parameter.

Comment: @zaph Indeed, sorry for my sloppy example. Maybe better formulation of question is: can nesting of (to attacker _per se_ unknown) combination of hashing algorithms give better security for the same amount of computation time? As computation time is something that will inevitably decrease over time...

Comment: No assuming you pick a currently secure cryptographic hash. The reason for the iteration is to slow down the attacker by requiring time consuming calculation, not that the hash function is not secure. Current password attacks are trying passwords from lists of frequently used passwords and the concept is to slow down the attacker, this can be effective if the attacker wants to brute force millions or passwords.

Comment: @zaph Thank you very much for your response. I've mixed pears and apples, assuming the scenario where attacker would focus (for (s)he has the needed computing power) to find the inverse of one hash (to break a  single super strong password). Cheers!

Comment: No current attacker can invert a SHA2 hash. Further there is no inversion since there may be many inputs that hash to the same value. PBKDF@ is Password Based Key Derivation Function, thus bringing in the password scenario.

Comment: Nope, won't make a difference. This question has already had an answer at the [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) site. Forgot where though.